# Yup schema validation password and confirmPassword doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, schema, yup, insomnia

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import User from '../models/User';

class UserController {
async store(req, res) {
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required(),
  email: Yup.string()
    .email()
    .required(),
  password: Yup.string()
    .required()
    .min(6),
});

if (!(await schema.isValid(req.body))) {
  return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Validation fails' });
}

const userExists = await User.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } });
if (userExists) {
  return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User already exists.' });
}
const { id, name, email, provider } = await User.create(req.body);
return res.json({ id, name, email, provider });
}

async update(req, res) {
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string(),
  email: Yup.string().email(),
  oldPassword: Yup.string().min(6),
  password: Yup.string()
    .min(6)
    .when('oldPassword', (oldPassword, field) =>
      oldPassword ? field.required() : field
    ),
  confirmPassword: Yup.string().when('password', (password, field) =>
    password ? field.required().oneOf([Yup.ref('password')]) : field
  ),
});

if (!(await schema.isValid(req.body))) {
  return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Validation fails' });
}

const { email, oldPassword } = req.body;
const user = await User.findByPk(req.userId);
if (user.email !== email) {
  const userExists = await User.findOne({
    where: { email },
  });
  if (userExists) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User already exists.' });
  }
}

if (oldPassword && !(await user.checkPassword(oldPassword))) {
  return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Password does not match.' });
}

const { id, name, provider } = await user.update(req.body);

return res.json({ id, name, email, provider });
  }  
}
export default new UserController();
```

Here it creates a normal user with the password 123456:

[image]

Here it should work, since the old password is the same as the password of the created user, and it should update the new password:

[image]

I want to try to understand how to make him understand the current password as oldpassword and update the password.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

validationSchema: Yup.object({
  password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  passwordConfirmation: Yup.string()
     .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
});
```

Comment: currently with this, when I change one of the inputs only the one being changed is validated, meaning that I need to change both to have the proper state, is there any way to force both to be checked when changing one?

Comment: @RenanSouza you can use test() method instead.

```Yup.object({
  password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  passwordConfirmation: Yup.string()
     .test('passwords-match', 'Passwords must match', function (value) {
      return this.parent.password === value
    })
})```

Comment: @HammedOyedele please create a post instead of a comment so we can upvote it and perhaps become selected as the best answer.

Comment: May be you guys have to put another required option for passwordConfirmation as well. ```Yup.object().shape({
  password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  passwordConfirmation: Yup.string()
    .required('Confirm password is required')
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match'),
});```

Comment: I used this in express end it works no problem. But in vue js it doesn't work maybe because of reactivity and instead I use .test in vue js like this .test('confirmation', 'Passwords do not match', (value) => password.value === value). by the way there are two variable password and password_confirmation

Comment: I would add a `.required()` to `passwordConfirmation` and remove the `null` value. Otherwise the form is valid when leaving the `passwordConfirmation` field empty.

Comment: This code gives me this error

`No overload matches this call.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(enums: readonly (string | Reference<unknown> | undefined)[], message?: Message<{ values: any; }> | undefined): StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">', gave the following error.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | Reference<unknown> | undefined'.ts(2769)`

Comment: @QasimRizvi Is there any response from yup on it ?

Comment: @YashKaranke 
I'm using it like this:

`passwordConfirmation: Yup.string().oneOf(
    [Yup.ref('password')],
    'Passwords must match',
  ),`
and it's working for me perfectly.

Note: I've removed null after `Yup.ref('password')`

Answer (score 84):

Based on @anoNewb answer and the request made by @Renan,

```
Yup.object({
  password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  passwordConfirmation: Yup.string()
    .test('passwords-match', 'Passwords must match', function(value){
      return this.parent.password === value
    })
})
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it gets called for every input, not only to changes of `passwordConfirmation`, and the value that gets passed is of that input. so for example, this fails:

Answer (score 37):

This is how I did it.

```
yup.object({
  password: yup
    .string()
    .required('Please enter your password.')
    .min(8, 'Your password is too short.'),
  retypePassword: yup
    .string()
    .required('Please retype your password.')
    .oneOf([yup.ref('password')], 'Your passwords do not match.')
});
```

Comment: This works. I noticed that oneOf does not trigger without required.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the latest version of Yup. Yup ^1.0.0

You no longer need to pass `null` as the second argument to `yup.ref` where the options arguments go: [docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#refpath-string-options--contextprefix-string--ref).

Here's how I would test the confirm password:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

validationSchema: Yup.object({
  password: Yup.string().required('Password is required').matches(
      /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*[\]{}()?"\\,><':;|_~`=+-])[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*[\]{}()?"\\,><':;|_~`=+-]{12,99}$/,
      'Must contain at least 12 Characters, 1 Uppercase, 1 Lowercase, 1 Special Character, and 1 Number'
    ),
  passwordConfirmation: Yup.string()
     .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords must match')
});
```

Note: I have added an extra .`matches()` regex in to the solution as for security most sites use some form of password validation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Harshal's answer above, but the API is a little different.

```js
import * as Yup from 'yup';

validationSchema: Yup.object({
  password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  passwordConfirmation: Yup.string()
     .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), undefined], 'Passwords must match')
});
```

Notice it's `undefined` instead of `null`.

Alternatively you can skip the `undefined` all together:

```js
import * as Yup from 'yup';

validationSchema: Yup.object({
  password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  passwordConfirmation: Yup.string()
     .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords must match')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Yup.object({
  password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  passwordConfirmation: Yup.string()
yup.string().when('password', ([password], schema, options) => {
  if (password!= '') {
     // if the password filled but passwordConfirmation not then return 
     required message
    if (options.value == '') {
      return schema.required();
    } else {
 // if the password filled and passwordConfirmation then return mismatch 
  message
      return schema.oneOf([password], 'validations.mismatch');
    }
  } else {
    return schema;
  }
})
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
onSubmit={(values)=>{
            const {confirmPassword,...data}=values;
            console.warn(data)
        }}
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation how this solves the OP's problem. [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/3124333)