# How to make password confirmation work correctly with yup?

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

I have the following code:

```
passwordConfirmation: yup.string().oneOf([yup.ref("password")], "Passwords do not match")
```

However, **this does not work if the passwordConfirmation field is empty** (using Formik). I don't understand why yup treats an empty value as correct. It's very unintuitive. I could add required(...) though, but I would like to only have one error message -- namely "Passwords do not match".

Comment: [Duplicate ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61862252/yup-schema-validation-password-and-confirmpassword-doesnt-work)

Comment: @tcconstantin how duplicate? specifically stating that this does not work if the passwordConfirmation field is empty, which is not what you linked to